# Prefer some function over ADL

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I want to use range-based `for` to iterate over the unicode code points in a UTF8 encoded `std::string`. I have defined my own `begin` and `end` in the global namespace but the `begin` and `end` in the `std` namespace are being preferred (i.e. those found by ADL). Is there any way to prefer my own functions?

Example:

```
const char* begin(const std::string& s) {
    std::cout << "BEGIN";
    return s.data();
}

const char* end(const std::string& s) {
    std::cout << "END";
    return s.data() + s.length();
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "asdf";

    for (char c : s)
        std::cout << c;
}
```

I want it to print `BEGINENDasdf` (or `ENDBEGINasdf`) but it prints `asdf`.

Is there no other way than to do a manual `for` using a qualified name?

Comment: Note: your base assumption is wrong: there is no ADL involved here, `s` is a `std::string` so `for (char c : s)` will behave as if using the _member_ form `s.begin()` and `s.end()`, not the non-member form `begin(s)` and `end(s)` (see remyabel's answer)

Comment: @gx_ yes, some of the answers below mentioned that. I had it reversed and thought that non-member `begin` was attempted first and member `begin` second.

Comment: @uk4321 You might be interested in [n3257](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3257.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap `std::string` in your own type. By making it a template you can customise any existing container and add your own range logic to it. It's not even that different from your first attempt.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename S>
struct custom_container {
    S &s_;

    custom_container (S &s) : s_(s) {}

    auto begin() -> decltype(s_.begin()) {
        std::cout << "BEGIN";
        return s_.begin();
    }

    auto end() -> decltype(s_.end()) {
        std::cout << "END";
        return s_.end();
    }
};

template <typename S>
custom_container make_container (S &s) {
     return custom_container <S> (s);
}


int main () {
    std::string t = "asdf";
    auto s = make_container(t);

    for (char c : s) {
        std::cout << c;
    }
}
```

Outputs

> BEGINENDasdf

Answer (score 6):

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 6.5.4/1:

> (...) *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are determined as follows:
>
> — if `_RangeT` is an array type, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are
>   `__range` and `__range + __bound`, respectively, (...);
>
> — if `_RangeT` is a class type, the *unqualiﬁed-id*s `begin` and `end` are
>   looked up in the scope of class `_RangeT` as if by class member access
>   lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) ﬁnds at least one declaration,
>   *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `__range.begin()` and `__range.end()`,
>   respectively;
>
> — otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(__range)` and
>   `end(__range)`, respectively, where `begin` and `end` are looked up with
>   argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2). For the purposes of this name
>   lookup, namespace `std` is an associated namespace.

So in other words, it will call `std::string`'s `begin` and `end` member functions (second list bullet). The correct solution is to provide a wrapper class as [anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20726714/1508519)'s answer suggests.

Note: If you use `-std=c++1y` you can omit the trailing decltype.

You can also write a typedef to make it less typing:

```
typedef custom_string<std::string> cs;

for (char c : cs(t)) {
    std::cout << c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do, at least at the point of use, this is to mark up your type for the purpose of special iteration.

First, some machinery:

```
template<class Mark, class T>
struct marked_type {
  T raw;
  marked_type(T&& in):raw(std::forward<T>(in)) {}
};
template<typename Mark, typename T>
marked_type<Mark, T> mark_type( T&& t ) {
  return {std::forward<T>(t)};
}
```

next, we invent a mark that says "iterate strangely", and overload begin/end:

```
struct strange_iteration {};
template<typename T>
auto begin( marked_type<strange_iteration, T> const& container )
  -> decltype( std::begin(std::forward<T>(container.raw)) )
{
  std::cout << "BEGIN";
  using std::begin;
  return begin(std::forward<T>(container.raw));
}
template<typename T>
auto end( marked_type<strange_iteration, T> const& container )
  -> decltype( std::end(std::forward<T>(container.raw)) )
{
  std::cout << "END";
  using std::end;
  return end(std::forward<T>(container.raw));
}
```

and then at point of use:

```
std::string s = "hello world";
for( char c : mark_type<strange_iteration>(s) ) {
  std::cout << c;
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

with the one note that I wrote `mark_type` to be overly generic.

Now, `mark_type<Foo>` will create references to lvalues, and create a moved-to copy of an rvalue, if passed to it.  In an iteration, its return value's lifetime will be extended by reference lifetime extension.

You can use this technique to do things like

```
for( char c : mark_type<reverse_iteration>(s) )
```

where now we instead iterate backwards, regardless of the container we have passed in.  The "creation of a copy" for rvalue is needed for constructs like this:

```
for( char c: mark_type<reverse_iteration>(mark_type<strange_iteration>(s))
```

where we daisy-chain the marks.  Lifetime extension only applies to the outermost return value, and our "create a copy and move" on rvalue is basically manual lifetime extension.

Finally, the `std::begin` use in the above code is better done in an ADL-admitting context in the return values.  Create a helper namespace like this:

```
namespace adl_helper {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  template<typename T>
  auto adl_begin(T&& t)->decltype( begin(std::forward<T>(t)) ); // no implementation
  template<typename T>
  auto adl_end(T&& t)->decltype( end(std::forward<T>(t)) ); // no implementation
  // add adl_cbegin, adl_rbegin etc in C++14
}
```

then replace `std::begin` in the `decltype`s in my above code with `adl_helper::adl_begin`, which emulates how `for( a:b )` loops find `begin` and `end` a touch better (not perfectly, but better).

C++1y may come with some machinery to remove the need for the above hack.

Sample code running: http://ideone.com/RYvzD0